# gettext_i18n_rails_js not working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, gettext

I already have these two gems in my application

```
gem 'faraday'
gem 'gettext_i18n_rails'
```

i wanted to get translations in my js file which resides in assets folder.
so i added gem

```
gem "gettext_i18n_rails_js", "~> 1.2.0"
```

and followed the guidelines in https://github.com/webhippie/gettext_i18n_rails_js. I didn't add any config files since i follow window.__ function. i called like this

```
window.__('sign_in.twitter')
```

in my js file but its throwing

```
Uncaught TypeError: window.__ is not a function
```

this error. Tried adding the config files as given in the documentation. Still not working. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add following line to your js manifest?

`//= require gettext/all`

`gettext/all.js` is the file where `window.__` function is defined. Check if it is really loaded.